# How to set callback function after onClick element?

Tags: javascript, html

My code is:

```
...
<li onclick="myFunc()">text</li>
...
```

and my javaScript code is:

```
function myFunc(){

}

function otherFunc(){

}
```

now i need to call 'otherFunc' function after 'li' clicked.

Comment: call 'otherFunc' inside 'myFunc' function!!!

Comment: you allright. thanks @MHS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `otherFunc()` at close of `myFunc()`

```
function myFunc(){
  // do stuff
  otherFunc()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<li onclick="myFunc(); otherFunc();">text</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following markup:

```
...
<li onclick="comprehensiveClickHandlerFunc()">text</li>
...
```

Use the following script:

```
function comprehensiveClickHandlerFunc(){
    myFunc();
    return otherFunc();
}

function myFunc(){

}

function otherFunc(){

}
```